Bokeh: how to create customJS button to clear DataTable selection?
I have a DataTable that I am using to select points in a plot, and I have created a "clear selection" button that is suppose to "unselect" all points, i.e. reset the selection. However, it appears to only operate on data that is in the current "view" of the DataTable, despite my customJS acting directly on the ColumnDataSource. Here is a MWE to show what I mean:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, push_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, CustomJS, CustomJSFilter, Slider, TableColumn, DataTable, SelectEditor, Button


x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
dfs = []
tstep = 1
ts = range(0, 100, tstep)
for t in ts:
    y = x**(t/50.)
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "t": t}))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
cds = ColumnDataSource(df)

t_slider = Slider(start=ts[0], end=ts[-1], step=tstep, value=0)

# Callback to notify downstream objects of data change
change_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=cds), code="""
    source.change.emit();
""")
t_slider.js_on_change('value', change_callback)

# JS filter to select data rows matching t value on slider
js_filter = CustomJSFilter(args=dict(slider=t_slider), code="""
const indices = [];

// iterate through rows of data source and see if each satisfies some constraint
for (let i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
    if (source.data['t'][i] == slider.value){
        indices.push(true);
    } else {
        indices.push(false);
    }
}
return indices;
""")
    
# Use the filter in a view
view = CDSView(filter=js_filter)
                           
# Add table to use for selecting data
columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="x", editor=SelectEditor()),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="y", editor=SelectEditor()),
]
data_table = DataTable(source=cds, columns=columns, selectable="checkbox", width=800, view=view)

p = figure(x_range=(0,10), y_range=(0,100))
p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=cds, view=view)

# Button to clear selection
clear_button = Button(label="Clear selection", button_type="success")
custom_js_button = CustomJS(args=dict(source=cds), code="""
source.selected.indices = [];
""")
clear_button.js_on_event("button_click", custom_js_button)

layout = column(p, t_slider, data_table, clear_button)
show(layout)

So, I have a CDSView that only shows one t slice at a time of the data in both the plot and the DataTable. I can select points in the datatable just fine, and they show up selected in the plot. For example:

If I then press the "clear" button with this t-slice selected, it works just fine. However, if I move the slider to a different t-slice and press the button, it does not work; if I slide back to the previous slice then the previous selection is still there. Why? I am wracking my brain and tried reading through the docs on these Bokeh objects but cannot understand why this would be happening. On the face of it the "clear" button has no idea what the current "view" or slider value is, it should just reset the selection.indices entirely. But somehow it doesn't, or the selection gets somehow restored by some hidden mechanism in the DataTable object?

Yes, more or less. The datatable is a third-party library wrapped by Bokeh, and it has its own notion of what rows are selected. That state has to be synced (both ways) with the CDS selection. When the table renders it updates the CDS with its view of selected rows. Crucially, it only reports based on the visible rows. So my speculation is that when the previously selected rows come back into view, the table suddenly thinks there is a selection, and overwrites the CDS selection (and "wins" by going "last"). All I can do is encourage a github issue.

Hmm, I see, that's unfortunate... I guess I will have to think of a different way to select data points other than a data table then...

Created https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/14040
